# Just set CSS Transition with JavaScript but it play animate without trigger

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have problem with css-transition which it play the transition before i need it.

The problem one is class **pageFlip-trigger** which I need to set its CSS by JavaScript

depend on img size for responsive design. but after JavaScript set css to it,

it play transition animate which is actually it need to move to

the point with out any transition animate first and then after trigger it then play.

IF you see my ponit in Javascript it's first time I set CSS to class pageFlip-trigger

It won't start transition Right??

what did I do wrong?? Please advice

Thank in advance.

HERE IS MY HTML

```
<div id="book-container">
    <section page='0' class='page-setup sectionContent-trigger'>
        <div class='page-wrapper pageContent-trigger'>
            <img src='image/test1.png' alt=''/>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="flip-container0" class="page-setup sectionFlip-trigger">
        <div id="flip-page0" class="page-wrapper pageFlip-trigger"></div>
    </section>
    <section id="flip-container1" class="page-setup sectionFlip-trigger">
        <div id="flip-page1" class="page-wrapper pageFlip-trigger"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

AND CSS

```
#book-container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 25px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 830px;
    max-height: 520px;
}
#book-container .page-setup{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#book-container .page-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#book-container img{
    max-width: 100%;
    /*max-width: 830px;*/
    /*max-height: 520px;*/
}
#book-container .sectionContent-trigger{
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.2s;

    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform;
    -ms-transition-duration: 1.2s;

    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 1.2s;
}
#book-container .pageContent-trigger{
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.2s;

    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform;
    -ms-transition-duration: 1.2s;

    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 1.2s;
}
#book-container .sectionFlip-trigger{
     -webkit-transform : translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
     -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
     -webkit-transition-duration: 1.2s;

     -ms-transform : translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
     -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform;
     -ms-transition-duration: 1.2s;

     transform : translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
     transition-property: transform;
     transition-duration: 1.2s;
 }
```

AND JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var pageWidth   = "";
    var pageHeight  = "";
    var currentFlip = 0;
    var currentPage = 0;

    $('section[page="0"] img').load(function(){
        pageHeight  = $(this).height();
        pageWidth   = $(this).width();
        $('#book-container').height(pageHeight);

        $('.pageFlip-trigger').css({
            'background': 'whitesmoke',
            '-webkit-transform': 'translate('+pageWidth+'px, 0px) rotate(0deg)',
            '-webkit-transition-property': '-webkit-transform',
            '-webkit-transition-duration': '1.2s',

            '-ms-transform': 'translate('+pageWidth+'px, 0px) rotate(0deg)',
            '-ms-transition-property': '-ms-transform',
            '-ms-transition-duration': '1.2s',

            'transform': 'translate('+pageWidth+'px, 0px) rotate(0deg)',
            'transition-property': 'transform',
            'transition-duration': '1.2s'
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: Do you experience javascript error? you're lacking semi-colon in your closing parenthesis at the btm of your script

Comment: nope sir. It's still ok

Comment: Might be easier to let people know what you expect. jsfiddle to the rescue: http://jsfiddle.net/wXwjr/ - it seems to me the transition takes effect as you intended, what exactly is the problem?